# Find COUNT of multiple tables that ST_INTERSECT a main table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

I have 3 tables. 1 polygon main table `polytable` (400,000 polys with 1000 unique names in the `polyname` column), and 2 point tables `pointtable1` (millions of points) and `pointtable2` (1000s of points). I'd like to return the distinct list of features from `polytable` with the COUNT of how many points intersect from `pointtable1` and also how many points intersect from `pointtable2`.

I want something like this:

```
polyname    pointtable1count   pointtable2count
red area    1                  2
blue area   0                  5
green area  9                  0
white area  0                  0
```

Notice how I'd like the polygon `white area` to still return even though there are no points that exist in it.

I've tried this query below but it seems to take too long. In a separate query when only using one of the point tables, I'm also having trouble returning polygons with 0 points within them (ie. `white area` would not be returned).

```
SELECT DISTINCT poly.polyname, COUNT(pnt1.*) as pointtable1count, COUNT(pnt2.*) as pointtable2count
FROM schema.polytable poly,
schema.pointtable1 pnt1,
schema.pointtable2 pnt2
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(poly.geom, pnt1.geom) OR ST_INTERSECTS(poly.geom, pnt2.geom)
GROUP BY poly.polyname
ORDER BY poly.polyname ASC;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, any `JOIN` combination would lead to a Cartesian product of matches between the two joined tables (i.e for each match of `pointtable1` there would be all matches from `pointtable2` in the result set).

Assuming proper indexes and updated statistics for both point tables, running

```
SELECT  ply.polyname, SUM(pnt1.cnt) AS pointtable1count, SUM(pnt2.cnt) AS pointtable2count
FROM    polytable AS ply,
        LATERAL (
          SELECT COUNT(pt.*) AS cnt
          FROM   pointtable1 AS pt
          WHERE  ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pt.geom)
        ) AS pnt1,
        LATERAL (
          SELECT COUNT(pt.*) AS cnt
          FROM   pointtable2 AS pt
          WHERE  ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pt.geom)
        ) AS pnt2
GROUP BY
        1
;
```

should be best performing.

---

You can compare (and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) to the semantically equivalent

```
SELECT pnt1.polyname, pnt1.cnt AS pointtable1count, pnt2.cnt AS pointtable2count
FROM   (
    SELECT  ply.polyname, COUNT(pointtable1.*) AS cnt
    FROM    polytable AS ply
    LEFT JOIN
            pointtable2 ON ST_Intersects(ply.geom, geom)
    GROUP BY
            1
) AS    pnt1
JOIN    (
    SELECT  ply.polyname, COUNT(pointtable2.*) AS cnt
    FROM    polytable AS ply
    LEFT JOIN
            pointtable2 ON ST_Intersects(ply.geom, geom)
    GROUP BY
            1
) AS    pnt2 USING(polyname)
;
```

for performance.

Comment: Thanks. Your first query ran in 5 minutes. Some typos in both queries though. `SELECT COUNT(c.*)` on line 9 in 1st query should be `SELECT COUNT(pt.*)` to match other aliases in that sub-query. Also query 2 has a few typos.

Comment: actually second query only seems to return rows where BOTH count columns do NOT = 0. First query is fine though and is accepted as answer.

Comment: @TheoF yeah I changed the overall alias scheme so often during write up that I mixed them...corrected. The second is based on `INNER JOIN`s; to include `NULL`s, change to `LEFT JOIN`s in both *inner queries*.